# how change css href to all .html documents with button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, href

i have this HTML code:

```
<link id="style1" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

with this js:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function toggle() {
    var el = document.getElementById("style1");
    if (el.href.match("css/style.css")) {
        el.href = "css/style-b.css";    
    }
    else {
        el.href = "css/style.css";  
    }
}

<button type="button" onclick="toggle()">Switch</button>
```

So, i need to make: when i click on this button to change the Css Href and to my other .html documents.. so let's say.. when i go from index.html to contact.html with link, i need there to be changed the css too.

How to do this? ( if there isn't a way to do this with HTML/JS do i have other options? )

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible ideas:
1. Use a cookie to save state and check that when you call each page (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)
2. Use local storage to save state. Generally speaking it acts like a cookie and it's a bit easier to access. (http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

so in you script you would need to add

```
localStorage.setItem("style", "-b");
```

then somewhere else in your code you would need to

```
localStorage.getItem("style"),
```

and do a check to see if it is there or not

```
var el = document.getElementById("style1");
var style = localStorage.getItem("style");
if(style !== null && style == "b"){
  el.href = "css/style-b.css";
} else {
  el.href = "css/style.css";
}  

function toggle() {
 var el = document.getElementById("style1");
 if (el.href.match("css/style.css")) {
   el.href = "css/style-b.css"; 
   localStorage.setItem("style", "b");   
 }
 else {
   el.href = "css/style.css";
   localStorage.setItem("style", "a");  
 }
}
```

Comment: i'm beginner so maybe more help pls?

Comment: Added an example. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways, Either use a GET or POST variable with Javascript, that would be passed along to every page, or the proper way, with server-side session variables.